# Is it safe to close my laptop after pressing Shut Down?

Tags: laptop, sleep, shutdown

What actually happens when I close the laptop (lower the screen)?

I know that if it's just on the desktop normally, it will go to sleep. But what if it's already shutting down?

I guess it will ignore the sleep signal and continue shutting down normally, but is there any chance that when I open it again it will resume the shutdown sequence that had been paused when I closed the laptop  earlier?

Or is it 100% safe to close the laptop screen after it starts to shut down?

Comment: I personally have my Windows laptop set to do nothing when the lid is closed. I have never had an issue starting a shutdown sequence and closing the lid during it. However, this may not always be the case with default lid closure settings (usually puts laptop to sleep).

Comment: I have melted the feet off a laptop by pressing shutdown, closing the lid and putting it in my bag. needless to say it didn't shutdown, and generated quite a bit of heat it that enclosed space.

Answer (score 0):

It is normally safe, but not 100% safe. I have seen a shutdown fail. Rarely to be sure, but I wait until the machine is truly off before closing the lid.

Any recent machine I have seen will shut down quite quickly - usually well under 2 minutes.

It is not worth having an issue the next morning.